bash script quoting frustration
This problem is driving me crazy.  From the command prompt I can enter this command and it works as expected (records where the INFO/RegionType tag contains the value Core are emitted in the output file):
bcftools filter -i "INFO/RegionType='Core'" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

But when I try to put the command in a bash script things go awry.  This seems to be due to the single and double quotes?  I tried various permutations of escaping quotes with no success.  Finally I tried the approach described here:
How to include double quote within string while from value of variable
to store the filter string in a variable and reference the variable. From my script:
filter_string=INFO/RegionType="'Core'"
bcftools filter -i \""$filter_string"\" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

This completes without an error but the command is not interpreting the filter correctly as evidenced by the fact that no records are included in the output file, whereas the command given directly from the command prompt yields 3124 records in the output file.
What might be going on here?

A minimal example of the input file that works with bcftools and reproduces the issue (note that all whitespace in the lines starting with chr1 needs to be single tabs, not spaces):
##fileformat=VCFv4.2
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##INFO=<ID=AC,Number=A,Type=Integer,Description="Allele count in genotypes, for each ALT allele, in the same order as listed">
##INFO=<ID=RegionType,Number=.,Type=String,Description="whatevs">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=249250621,assembly=hg19>
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  sample1
chr1    103385791   .   C   G   1182.77 PASS    AC=1;   GT  0/1
chr1    103471456   .   CCAT    C   2848.73 PASS    AC=2;RegionType=Core    GT  1/1


It absolutely should be possible to have the command (as shown) work in a bash script.    Did you put it into your script exactly as you showed it in the question?    (Or did you immediately start messing with quotes and variables?)    Exactly what happened?    “things” should not “go awry”.

It would really help if you could include a testable example. At the very least, show us a variant line with the RegionType set in its Info field so we can see what it looks like in order to reproduce. Is it actually RegionType='Core' in the vcf file, or is it RegionType=Core?

I added a simple example that reproduces the behavior for me. Please check and change it if your data are significantly different.

“From the command prompt” — Which shell is that?

Compared to cmd's idea of quoting bash is very sane.

The shell uses quotes to identify where words (tokens) should be separated. They are not usually part of the text that a command sees.

bcftools filter -i "INFO/RegionType='Core'" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz


Here, the double quotes tell the shell that INFO/RegionType='Core' is to be treated as a single word.
Bearing that in mind, this is what you want in the filter:
filter_string="INFO/RegionType='Core'"

You can see this is correctly captured:
echo "$filter_string"
INFO/RegionType='Core'

However, it's been noted that the bcftools tool officially expects strings to be double quoted rather than single quoted (i.e. "Core" instead of 'Core'), and here you could simply swap the type of quotes being used:
filter_string='INFO/RegionType="Core"'
echo "$filter_string"
INFO/RegionType="Core"

In either case you can then pass this to your command, again bearing in mind that quotes tell the shell how to parse and split (or not split) words as tokens:
bcftools filter -i "$filter_string" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

NB when you're testing remember that (almost!) anything that can go in a script can be typed directly on the command line, and vice versa. For example, you don't need a script to test the snippets in my answer. It's an incredibly useful way of checking something works before burying it in a script.

Looking at the tool's manual on expressions, it seems the string Core should be double-quoted.  But that's just a matter of swapping the type of quotes around, so that's trivial.  @terdon may be more familiar with this tool than I am.

@Kusalananda assuming the actual VCF line contains RegionType=Core, then the filter command should indeed be "INFO/RegionType='Core'", but bcftools filter -i "$filter_string" works fine as long as the Core is stored as 'Core' in the variable. So no, Core just needs to be quoted, not double quoted. Chris's command here works fine on an example I cooked up locally.

@terdon I've just updated my answer as it appears the official documentation expects double quotes instead of singles. It's good to hear that the tool doesn't really mind, though

Ok, Thanks.  G-Man intuited correctly that I did not try simply including the string directly in the command line before assuming the quoting would not work as-is.  But it does work to simply construct the command thusly: bcftools filter -i "INFO/RegionType='Core'" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz  However, if the string is placed in a variable instead, Chris is correct that the variable should be defined with filter_string="INFO/RegionType='Core'" and used with bcftools filter -i "$filter_string" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

Interestingly, bcftools doesn't seem to care which kind of quotes are used, so the variable can also be defined with filter_string='INFO/RegionType="Core"' and it will work fine.

The link you posted is probably contributing your confusion.
If you have experience using conventional programming languages or even spreadsheets this will not help either. For those tools, quote chars are used as delimiters of string values while (most/all) shells use quote chars to group together entities. So when bash reads the folowing, it interprets the argument as the same value before passing it to echo:

echo /something/somewhere/athing
echo "/something/somewhere/athing"
echo /something"/somewhere/"athing

This becomes important when you consider that bash treats whitespace, by default, as a separator of things. If your thing has (for example) a space character in the middle, bash sees it as 2 things UNLESS you either wrap it in quotes, or tell bash not to treat that whitespace as a separator by escaping it:

echo "something somewhere athing"
echo something\ somewhere\ athing

Getting back to your use-case,
bcftools filter -i "INFO/RegionType='Core'" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

Here bash sees the double quotes around the argument, but removes them from the data passed to the bcftools executable. bcftools sees
INFO/RegionType='Core'

If we want bash to treat quote characters differently, then just like spaces, we escape them. Telling bash bcftools filter -i \""INFO/RegionType='Core'"\" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz the outer set of double quotes are included in the data passed to bcftools - it sees
"INFO/RegionType='Core'"

Those double quotes don't exist in the data you are searching.
You simply need to substitute $filter_string for INFO/RegionType='Core' to get your script to work:
filter_string=INFO/RegionType="'Core'"
bcftools filter -i "$filter_string" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

In many cases, the quotes aren't actually impacting the functionality, but in your case, the double quotes also act to preserve the single quotes in the argument. If you tried to run:
bcftools filter -i INFO/RegionType='Core' -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

bash would pass the argument as INFO/RegionType=Core
The other consideration is how bash treats single quotes ' vs double quotes ". Bash expands values enclosed in double quotes (e.g. a thing appearing after a $) but does not do this with single quotes other than scrict escaping, e.g.
bcftools filter -i 'INFO/RegionType=\'Core\'' -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

Has the same effect as
bcftools filter -i "INFO/RegionType='Core'" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

but
bcftools filter -i "$filter_string" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz

is NOT the same as
bcftools filter -i '$filter_string' -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz


no, 'INFO/RegionType=\'Core\'' is not the same as "INFO/RegionType='Core'". Backslashes don't work within single quotes. (They do in $'...', though, but that's different.) The syntax highlighting here actually knows that, you can see the 'INFO/RegionType=\' part and the ending of the line from ' -Oz -o ... green. 'INFO/RegionType=\'Core\'' is the single-quoted string 'INFO/RegionType=\', unquoted Core, escaped single quote, and then a single quote starting a quoted string

Ok thanks.  That makes sense.  I think I originally tried bcftools filter -i INFO/RegionType='Core' -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz in the script and didn't realize it was not passing along the single quotes.  bcftools gave the message Error: the tag "Core" is not defined in the VCF header which was rather a red herring in terms of diagnosing my bad command syntax.  Using my original variable definition and the command bcftools filter -i "$filter_string" -Oz -o temp.core.vcf.gz temp2.vcf.gz does indeed work fine.

Based on @ChrisDavies answer this version is the easiest one:
filter_string='INFO/RegionType="Core"'

But you can also use this one.
filter_string="INFO/RegionType=\"Core\""

This is more useful when your string contains variables.
Sometimes, when you have a mix of quotes and/or backslashes, then it can make sense to concatenate several string parts. Each part may use single quotes or double quotes, whatever fits better. For example
filter_string=one"'two'"'"three"'
echo $filter_string
one'two'"three"

